# melonjs-api wont load my map and receive no error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-engine, melonjs

Im following the tutorial: http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/
At the end of part 2 you should be able to see your map.

Melonjs just loads and stops, i get no error.
my files: http://nicksegers.be/game1/

I did teh tutorial 3times and just cant get it to work.
Always the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the last line of game.js to display PLAY instead of MENU.

```
// Start the game.
me.state.change(me.state.MENU);
```

Change to:

```
// Start the game.
me.state.change(me.state.PLAY);
```

I opened an issue on their tracker: https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/issues/402